# Understanding the JTAG connector/adaptor attached to a smartphone

Tags: integrated-circuit, jtag

This stuff use a JTAG Box method but I don't understand where exactly wires is welted onto the smartphone circuit board.

Why they use the green adaptor over the board?

[image: first]
[image: second]

Source: http://sysforensics.org/2016/08/jtaging-mobile-phones/

Comment: I think that may be a logic level shifter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That small green board likely just contains a surface-mounted pin header style shrouded connector on it's bottom side (hidden) that is connected to the mating connector on the cell phone's motherboard. That connector exposes the JTAG signals.

Here is another example:

[image]

The JTAG port is circled in red and enlarged in inset. This motherboard is missing the connector on the motherboard side, so that green adapter PCB wouldn't be necessary. Instead, you would have to solder ("weld" in your terminology) high gauge wires to the exposed pads on the PCB like in your photo between the green adapter PCB and the larger adapter PCB.

That second PCB is yet another adapter that goes from the bare soldered wires into a connector that is compatible with the JTAG interrogator unit (visible in the background with the blue LED).

Comment: mm.., so wires are called `gauge wires` but what type of signal transport ? a standard 5 volt eletrical voltage  ? But if I have not this exposed pads on motherboard so I could not use green adapter PCB and I could not enter in any way. I wish understand if bare soldered wires is that pad position is the only solution to access to relative ARM processor chip or if I can use another point of smartphone circuit to sold my wires. I imagine that here is may to be also a signal modulation problem to make a bridge without standard pad point, right ?

Comment: @Peter -- Wire gauges are a measure of how large a wire is, either in diameter or cross sectional area (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_gauge). The signal levels, connection points, use of a connector, etc... are all _specific to the design of the motherboard and MCU/CPU chosen by that specific phone maker_. Without more detail on your exact motherboard (manufacturer, model, schematics, et al.), it will be impossible for anyone here to assist you further unfortunately.

Comment: thanks for clarification, so this is a productor MUST for assistance. So if I have an LG G3 where I need to look for motherboard specifications ? Thanks for clarifications

Comment: @Peter -- You might try searching at https://forum.xda-developers.com